# How can I print the intermediate results in CPLEX?

Tags: php, variables, var, cplex, conflict

Other than decision variables, there must be some other variables in the subject block of the C-PLEX software. For calculations and analysis, we may have to use it. How to print other variables into an Excel sheet?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: minimize sum(i in 0..3)(c1[i]*pg[i]^2 + c2[i]*pg[i] + c3[i]);
subject to
{forall(i in 0..3)
     p[i]==V[i]*(sum(j in 0..3)(V[j]*(G[i][j]*deltacos[i][j]+B[i][j]*deltasin[i][j])));
     p[i]-pg[i]+pd[i]==0;
  forall(i in 0..3)
     q[i]==V[i]*(sum(j in 0..3)(V[j]*(G[i][j])));
     q[i]-Qg[i]+qd[i]==0;  
  //forall(i in 0..3) 
 // pg[i]<=30;
  
  }
In this code I want to print the values of p[i]

Answer (score 0):

Any array of dvar or data can be written into Excel

See https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/write3Darray.mod

```
range A=1..2;
range B=1..3;
range C=1..4;


dvar int X[A][B][C];

subject to
{
forall(a in A,b in B,c in C) X[a][b][c]==a*b*c;
}

tuple someTuple{
int a;
int b;
int c;
int value;
};


{someTuple} someSet = {<i,j,k,X[i][j][k]> | i in A, j in B, k in C};
```

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/write3Darray.dat

```
SheetConnection sheet("write3Darray.xlsx");

someSet to SheetWrite(sheet,"A1:D24");
```